# How to reduce the build time while cross-compiling atlas for armv7?

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, atlas

I am trying to cross compile the atlas library for an armv7 cortex-a9 processor.
When I try to `make build` it takes more than five hours to build the library from source. I think the problem is it runs all sanity tests.  Is there a way to skip this?

**Host system**: *ubuntu 16.4* in a virtual box with 4gb ram allocated , and 2 cores.
**Target system**: cortex a9, small endian armv7 architecture

**Build process**:

```
export PATH =$PATH:PATH TO ARM TOOL CHAIN FROM BUILDROOT
export CC=arm-linux-gcc
export ARCH=arm
export RANLIB=arm-linux-ranlib
export STRIP=arm-linux-strip
export LD=arm-linux-ld
export CPP=arm-linux-cpp
export AR=arm-linux-ar
export AS=arm-linux-as
export FC=arm-linux-gfortran

downloaded the atlas library

tar -xf atlas.3.10.3.tat.gz
cd ATLAS
mkdir test
cd test
../configure -Si archdef 0
make build
```

It would be helpful to know if I am missing some steps in between or any build commands to be included while make so that the sanity tests don't happen and I
get the output any sooner?

Comment: First you need to profile the build somehow to locate the places that take time.  Have you done that?  There are compiler 'caches' that will reduce time.  Also, I guess you have a windows host with a Ubuntu virtual machine.  Compile/build will be at least 50% to 100% faster with a native Linux build.  Switch to a dual boot or get a cygwin type build working.

Answer (score 0):

Though it doesn't answer your question, just FYI - modern approach is to use `docker` for building, CI tests and so on. VM (such as VirtualBox) will eat more resources.

For ARM cross-compilation you may consider https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross it has image for Cortex-A9 as well.

If you makefile runs long tests, then there may be an option to skip them indeed. Check the makefile if the author implemented something for that purpose.